# How do I randomly split class into subclass based on predefined quota in tibble

Tags: r

How do I randomly split class into subclass based on predefined quota in tibble.

Below is an example. I want to create a new column `Subclass` assign `X` and `Y` such that each `Class` is randomly split into `X` and `Y` based on predefined numbers.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Class = c(rep("A", 120), rep("B", 200), rep("C", 300)), 
              Values = runif(620))


I want to create a new column `Subclass` assign `X` and `Y` such that each `Class` is randomly split into `X` and `Y` based on predefined numbers.

df2 <- tibble(Class = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
             Subclass = rep(c("X", "Y"), 3), 
             predefined_split = c(47, 73, 126, 74, 101, 199))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that predefined splits align with input data, you could generate a random sequence of `"X", "Y"` from split quotas and bind that to `df`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(Class = c(rep("A", 120), rep("B", 200), rep("C", 300)), 
             Values = runif(620))

df2 <- tibble(Class = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
              Subclass = rep(c("X", "Y"), 3), 
              predefined_split = c(47, 73, 126, 74, 101, 199))

# pivot wider (cols: Class, X, Y), 
# generate a random sequence of "X" and "Y" values for each predefined split set,
# unnest resulting list column 
sample_seq <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Subclass, values_from = predefined_split) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Subclass = c(rep("X", X), rep("Y", Y))[sample.int(X+Y)] %>% list(), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  unnest_longer(Subclass)

sample_seq
#> # A tibble: 620 × 2
#>    Class Subclass
#>    <chr> <chr>   
#>  1 A     X       
#>  2 A     X       
#>  3 A     X       
#>  4 A     Y       
#>  5 A     Y       
#>  6 A     Y       
#>  7 A     X       
#>  8 A     X       
#>  9 A     Y       
#> 10 A     Y       
#> # ℹ 610 more rows

# check counts:
table(sample_seq)
#>      Subclass
#> Class   X   Y
#>     A  47  73
#>     B 126  74
#>     C 101 199

# check if Class columns match:
identical(sample_seq$Class, df$Class)
#> [1] TRUE

# bind columns:
df_classified <- bind_cols(df, Subclass = sample_seq$Subclass)
df_classified
#> # A tibble: 620 × 3
#>    Class Values Subclass
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   
#>  1 A      0.941 X       
#>  2 A      0.656 X       
#>  3 A      0.484 X       
#>  4 A      0.304 Y       
#>  5 A      0.640 Y       
#>  6 A      0.732 Y       
#>  7 A      0.371 X       
#>  8 A      0.473 X       
#>  9 A      0.238 Y       
#> 10 A      0.721 Y       
#> # ℹ 610 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>